# React.js TDD - Headless AND Jest?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tdd, phantomjs, jestjs

I am trying to get things straight.  Would I use a headless browser AND something like a Jest test framework or does Jest essentially provide the same tooling something like PhantomJS would provide?   And you use headless browsers to test what behavior on the browser vs. Jest that tests that React component behavior works as expected...